# Java Supplier/Consumer/Runnable? How to invoke method when it is supplied as a a string argument

Tags: java

I need a help. User supplying method with its arguments as a string. My code need to run this method.

How we can we achieve this using Supplier/Consumer/Runnable. This can be done using reflection but I want to avoid it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InvokeStringArgument{
    public static Supplier<String> invokeMe(String returnStr){
        return new Supplier<String>(){
            public String get(){
                System.out.println("Success");
                return returnStr;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //invokeMe("MyValue").get();

        System.out.println("Please enter method to invoke:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String methodName = sc.next();
        //Need a code which will run the method when passed as a string
        //For example user input it as invokeMe("MyValue")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `invokeMe(methodName).get()`?  Or are you trying to have the user _name the method_ and there's some method somewhere?  (That's going to require reflection, and it's going to be yucky.)

Comment: I want when `invokeMe("MyValue")` when supplied as a string from external source, it should get invoked and run successfully.

Comment: _What_ should get invoked?  Is the user themselves writing the string `"invokeMe(\"MyValue\")"`?  (That's going to be _very_ difficult to do; you're going to have to parse the input yourself.)

Comment: Yes, user  themselves writing the string "invokeMe(\"MyValue\")" as a string argument to some other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got some time today to look into these pending things. Achieved solution which at this time confirms to my requirement. Used BeanShell and reflection to get this done as below

```
package beanshell;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import bsh.EvalError;
import bsh.Interpreter;

public class InvokeStringArgument{
    public static Supplier<String> invokeMe(String returnStr){
        return new Supplier<String>(){
            public String get(){
                System.out.println("Success: Received string '"+returnStr+"'");
                return returnStr;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws EvalError {
        //invokeMe("MyValue").get();

        System.out.println("Please enter string to evaluate:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = sc.next();

        Interpreter i = new Interpreter();

        Object evalSource = i.eval("public class EvalUserInput extends beanshell.InvokeStringArgument{"
                + "public void evaluserInput(){"
                + userInput+""
                + "}"
                + "}");
        try{
            Class<?> noparams[] = {};
            Class<?> cls = (Class) evalSource;
            Object obj = cls.newInstance();
            cls.getDeclaredMethod("evaluserInput", noparams).invoke(obj, null);
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

From the console:

```
Please enter string to evaluate:
invokeMe("MyValue").get();
Success: Received string 'MyValue'
```

Comment: Please only use this solution **if you trust the user 100%**, since it allows running any code, including malicious one.